# Как правильно склоняется фамилия Побожий ?

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Был такой инженер-изыскатель Александр Побожий, который строил ж/д Чум-Салехард-Игарка в 1949-53 годах. Как писать его фамилию в родительном и других падежах?

Answer (score 3):

В примечании 4 в книге "История Мертвой дороги" (автор В. Гриценко) о фамилии Побожий следующее: "По свидетельству очевидца (...) автор (книги Мертвая дорога) носил фамилию с ударением на третий слог - ПобожИй". Поэтому в родительном падеже фамилия эта должна писаться "Побожия", а не так , как это стало распространено в документах еще во время строительства дороги - "Побожего"

Comment: Это ценная информация, но увы, вывод о форме родительного падежа не аргументирован. Толстой тоже имел ударение на последнем слоге, но оставался при этом Толстым, а не Толстоем.

Answer (score 2):

Побожий - фамилия малорусская(украинская), из того же ряда, что и Крадий, Бабий, Палий, Павлий, Джеджелий(таких довольно много)- этнически они разного генеза, но форма устоявшаяся, с ударением только на последнем слоге, и склонение совершенно определенное(в украинском языке). Думаю, в русском употреблениии не надо мучиться, нужно просто использовать украинскую(малорусскую) традицию и склонять: Побожия, Побожию, о Побожии и т.д.

Comment: То есть так, как склоняются существительные на -ий: планетарий, лекторий.

Comment: Вы лучше для каждого падежа просклоняйте, а то ничего неясно

Comment: >>>Вы лучше для каждого падежа просклоняйте, а то ничего неясно  
  
Лучше уж вы это сделайте. ))) А то не ясно, чего вам не ясно.

Касательно рекомендации "использовать украинскую традицию". Нет и еще раз нет. Всегда стоит смотреть, насколько это соответствует руссскому языку. А то так мы и фамилии на -ко начнём склонять.

Это я ао части смысле обоснований. А конкретно по отношению к данной фамилии "украинский" вариант, пожалуй, правилен . Но не из общих соображений, а потому, что так склонял её сам носитель, не потерявший, видимо, связи с украинским языком.

Comment: >Вы лучше для каждого падежа просклоняйте, а то ничего неясно
И. кто?     Побожий  
Р. кого?    Побожия  
Д. кому?    Побожию
В. кого?    Побожия  
Т. кем?     Побожием
П. о ком? о Побожии

Comment: Если кто-то склоняет фамилии на -ко, это не является какой-то ошибкой, примеров не только из классики, но и вполне современных, на самом деле, вокруг немало. И на Украине склоняют далеко не все говорящие по-украински(или по-русски), только, пожалуй, продвинутые грамотеи, как и у нас.
Что до склонения фамилий на -ий, "украинский" вариант также является и русским. Если Побожий, Джеджелий, Бабий - безусловно "родом" из Украины, то Багрий, к примеру, довольно распространен в наших северных краях с давних времен.

Comment: А почему в родительном и винительном падежах надо писать Побожия, а не Побожьего или Побожего ?

Comment: Перечитайте все внимательно.

Comment: >>>Если кто-то склоняет фамилии на -ко, это не является какой-то ошибкой...      

Во-первых, в русском язвке это **является** ошибкой (об этом в другой раз), во-вторых, я упомянул об этом исключительно чтобы показать ошибочность идеи замствовать правила изменения по падежам из языка-источника вместе с самим словом. Ваши же рассуждения, построенные на том, что кто-то или где-то так говорит никак не могут быть аргументом. Диалекты - не норма для общелитературного языка, а украинский язык - это другой язык, со своими правилами и грамматикой пусть и похожей во многом.

Comment: 2 Варяг-91:
Сами читайте внимательно, здесь нет ответа на мой вопрос. Зато явно обозначены две точки зрения - одна за склонение в Р и В в виде "Побожия", а другая т.зр. допускает также склонение в виде "Побож(ь)его"

Answer (score 1):

Мужские фамилии, типа этой, могут склоняться по падежам. То есть, будет Побожего, Побожему и т.д.

Comment: А как будет во множественном числе? Например Александр и Мария Побожий, чета, семейство и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке я не знаю прилагательных с ударным окончанием -ий (-ый), в то время как окончание -ой всегда ударное. Поэтому Толстого мы безболезненно склоняем по парадигме прилагательного, а ПобожИй логичнее склонять как существительные, оканчивающиеся на -ий (санаторий, лекторий и т. п.)

Comment: Да не бывает логики в том, что касается имен собственных.  
А русском много чего нет.  
Много вы знаете **существительных**, оканчиающивающихся на ударное -ий? О то ж.  
А парадигма склонения а русском не зависит от места ударения (за исключением нескольких весьма специфических и заранее оговоренных случаев).   
Я отнбдь не исключаю субстантивный вариан склонения, более того, интуитивно он мне тоже он кажется более вероятным с точки зрения выбора носителя фамилии. Но утверждать сто-то определённое, да ещё на основании весьма сомнительно "логичности" поостерёгся бы.

Comment: Да про зависимость парадигмы склонения от ударения я вроде не говорила. Я про то, почему Толстого мы легко склоняем и почему Побожий по той же схеме звучит нелепо.

Comment: Во-первых, не вижу ничего нелепого в звучании фамилии.  
Во-вторых, что действительно нелепо звучит, так это ваше заявление о том, что вы не говорили. ну русским же по белому: "В русском языке я не знаю прилагательных с ударным окончанием -ий (-ый)".

Comment: И при чём тут склонение? Прилагательные в мужском роде и с ударным окончанием  -ой, и с безударным -ий склоняются одинаково. И нелапо звучит не фамилия, а формф этой фамилии в косвенных падежах: ПобожЕго, ПобожЕму и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Вы знаете, самое правильное будет избегать фраз, где эта фамилия стоит в косвенных падежах. Особенно - во множественном числе.

Дело в том, что рекомендации о формах косвенных падежей сталкиваются с необходимостью решить два вопроса: является ли фамилия фамилией славянского происхождения и, если да, то является ли она формой прилагательного. Если на первый вопрос можно достаточно уверенно ответить положительно, то на второй ответ может дать только носитель. По возможности лучше просто спросить, как он предпочитает склонять свою фамилию.

Возможные варианты для мужской фамилии (как свежий, хорунжий или как кий, радий)

И. Александр Побожий   
Р. Александр Побож(ь)его/Побожия  
Д. Александру Побож(ь)ему/Побожию  
В. Александра Побож(ь)его/Побожия  
Т. Александра Побож(ь)им/Побожием  
П. (об) Александре Побож(ь)ем/Побожии/Побожие
*Интуитивно предочел бы второй вариант.*

Женская фамилия по падежам не изменяется.

С множественным числом дело ещё хуже. По правилам, предполагая субстантивный вариант склонения: *Александр и Мария Побожии, супруги Побожии, братья Побожии, брат и сестра Побожии, сестры Побожии* и соответственные формы в косвенных падежах. Но увы, помимо тех же вариантов склонения - по типу прилагательного и по типу существительного - возникают ещё варианты типа Побожии/Побожьи. Кроме того в силу недостаточной "русскости" фамилии возможны варианты в выборе между склоняемым и несклоняемым вариантом. Сравните: Братья Гримм, но братья Гонкуры, сестры Пресс.

В этой ситуации я могу только посоветовать в нарушение всех правил не изменять фамилию во множественном числе, т.е. считать её как бы иностранной. Тогда будет "(Александр и Мария) Побожий" - во всех падежах.

Comment: Если как радий. то в предложном  - о Побожии

Comment: Точно! Ещё один вариант. О радии, хотя о кие (вроде бы ещё о Вие). Исправил.

Comment: У всех односложных - е (О Бие, Лие, Вие и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

Скажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли склонять мужскую фамилию Пресс? Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: А почему нет? Как и все принадлежащие лицам мужского пола фамилии с нулевым окончанием.

Comment: Не можно, а нужно.

Comment: Ох, не ту кнопку нажал... Теперь не могу тревогу поднять. Вообще-то другой вопрос, а не ответ.